# Showing two different research kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I would like to know if we can made two different research and visualize them in the same window; for example I have two different VM and there is 7 CPUS in each one, so I'd like to show the average of use for 7 CPUS on VM1 and VM2 in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that could help someone: 
I used split series; if you have a field that contains the name of your VM you can use sub aggregation-->terms--->your field.

But in my case I had 7 CPUS for each VM so using that I will get 14 visualizations. I used so filters (sub aggregation) and then two filters; in the first one just the name of VM0 and in the second filter VM1.